# Is Directory relative to local server path or public URL path?

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

I understand that [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) refers to server's local path (on disk), i.e. with

```
<VirtualHost :80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite1/
```

browsing http://example.com/foo/index.html will access `/home/www/mysite1/foo/index.html` on the server.

Then, should I use (that sometimes seems to work):

```
<Directory "/">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(isn't it strange to reference to `/`, i.e. root of server's filesystem?)

or should I copy/paste the `DocumentRoot` into `Directory` like this:

```
DocumentRoot /home/www/mysite1/
<Directory "/home/www/mysite1/">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

?

If so, this is annoying to have to copy/paste into `Directory` each time we modify the `DocumentRoot`, why is this **duplication** of configuration path needed? Isn't there a way to say `Require all granted` *for everything* without having to duplicate the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Configuration Sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html) in the Apache manual.

[`<Directory>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) does, indeed, refer to the file system path.

You can specify rules for an entire website, independent of locations on the filesystem, with [`<Location>`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#location).

Comment: Thank you. Could you just include an example with `Location`? What should I do instead of `<Directory "/home/www/mysite1/">
Require all granted
</Directory>` to avoid duplicating the filesystem path?

Comment: The syntax is the same. `<Location "/">`, and there are examples in the manual I linked to.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. So basically I can remember that `<Directory FileSystemPath>` and `<Location URLPath>`, is that a good rule of thumb?

Answer (score 0):

I used this setting

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName seminarium.loc
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/seminarium.loc/public

    <Directory /var/www/seminarium.loc/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

   ErrorLog /var/www/seminarium.loc/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/seminarium.loc/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The path in the directory specifies the directory to which the options will be applied. It is natural to exclude possible conflicts, it is desirable to specify the path to the DocumentRoot as if there are several sites with "/" they will overwrite options to each other

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how it works? (relative to the question)

Comment: So is it mandatory to each time copy/paste the DocumentRoot path into Directory path, to be able to set Require all granted? Isn't there a way to do it without duplicating the path?

Comment: You do not need to specify the Directory block in the {site}.conf and add them to /etc/apache2/default.conf
For parent directory with all websites
Example /var/www

Comment: What would be a default Directory in default.conf ?

Comment: Depends on where you store the sites
In my cases, it's /var/www/ . Directory www have directorys all my webistes:
/var/www/site1/
/var/www/site2/ ...